# Не отображается меню сайта при загрузке страницы

Tags: html, php

Добрый день, уважаемые программисты!

Хочу написать многостраничный сайт. Написал "шапочку", меню навигации и при помощи фреймов отображал страницы при клике на кнопки навигации. Всё работает, всё хорошо. Но результат меня не устраивает, поскольку при загрузке любой страницы, привязанной к кнопке навигации, шапочка и меню не отображаются. Знаю, что в РНР это возможно избежать (т.е. каждая страница содержит и "шапочку" и меню навигации), однако я не нашел литературы, в которой всё это описывается.

Прошу помочь советом, либо литературой. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вкратце.

Есть три файла (ваша терминология сохранена и расширена). header.html - "шапочка"
body.html - "тельце" - таких файлов много. Их мы по очереди будем "втыкать" в центр.
footer.html - "ножки".

Файл на php выглядит так:

```
<?php
//Ключ-значение: название страницы=>доступна ли
$avail_pages = array('body'=>true,'main'=>false,'contacts'=>true);
include 'header.html';
if(isset(avail_pages[$_GET['page']]) && avail_pages[$_GET['page']]){
include $_GET['page'].'.html';
}
include 'footer.html';
```

Ссылка на страницу выглядит так:

```
<a href="/index.php?page=contacts">контакты</a>
```

Литература - библия пользователя PHP 5 & Mysql.
Купите, почитайте. Не самая простая книжка, но для старта с нуля пойдет вполне.
И найти легко.

Comment: @knes, большое спасибо:)

Comment: Просто переводите, как есть. Интерпретатор не ожидает увидеть в этом месте [, но ожидает что-то еще. Скорее всего, точку с запятой. Посмотрите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: @knes исправил, там знака "$" перед "avail_pages" не хватало.

Comment: @knes всё работает исправно, большое Вам спасибо. Проблема лишь с кодировкой: почему-то тексты кракозяблями выводит)